# Gridview delete not working with DeleteParameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have an issue where a Gridview delete is not working correctly. It seems to have something to do with the DeleteCommand and the DeleteParameters. For example, if I give a static value to the DeleteCommand, rather than use the DeleteParameter, the gridview does delete the record with the value I specify statically. Code is below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="testGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Test_ID" 
        DataSourceID="dsourceTest">
    <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Test_ID" HeaderText="Test_ID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Test_ID" />
            ...MORE COLUMNS HERE...
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsourceTest" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Test_ID, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, COALESCE(C7, '') AS C7, C8 FROM TestTable1" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TestTable1] WHERE [Test_ID] = @Test_ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Test_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So with the DeleteCommand above as it is, the Delete won't work. But if I change it to `DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TestTable1] WHERE [Test_ID] = 27"` for example, and I hit a Delete button in the Gridview, it would delete the record with the Test_ID of 27.

Comment: Is Test_ID included in your <Columns> definition?

Comment: Hi @Rob, yes, it's there, see edit above. Should that matter though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...I had to change the DeleteCommand to `DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ClientService_AP] WHERE [Action_Plan_ID] = @original_Test_ID"` because I also had the statement `OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"` in the SqlDataSource.